# Understanding the cache size of arbitrary callback data in python telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have recently read the `python-telegram-bot` [docs](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Arbitrary-callback_data) that explains the advantages of `arbitrary_callback_data`. I did not understand this sentence in the docs:

> PTB stores the callback data objects in memory. Additionally, to that, it stores a mapping of CallbackQuery.id to the corresponding UUID. By default, both storages contain a maximum number of 1024 items.

What does 1024 represent? In my code I have some inline buttons that for example remove a document from Mongodb. Like the example below:

`InlineKeyboardButton(text='title',callback_data=f'delete_doc_{the_id_of_doc}')`

Does that mean for instance if I have millions of ids, It exceeds the limit that is set to 1024 by default? Because the `callback_data` of each button in my code is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1024 is the number of complete keyboards that are kept in memory. For each keyboard, the unique identifiers of the buttons plus the actualy data of the button are kept in memory.

Note that as long as `delete_doc_{the_id_of_doc}` is shorter than 64 chars, there is maybe not much added benefit for you in using this feature.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks. In the doc that is linked above there is a paragraph about the security of normal callback_data and it is mentioned that since arbitrary ones use UUID it is safer. Do you think that normal callback_data is safe for operations like deleting something in database?

Comment: And also I have read in the docs that if data exceeds 1024 it relies on LRU. 
I want to simply know that does my bot still runs ok after it exceeds 1024?

Comment: The security question is up to you to decide, I can't judge your use case. Yes, your bot will continue to run fine after exceeding the 1024 limit, the "older" buttons will just not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks. It means a lot that you take the time to answer. I might have millions of ids in my database. So i may need to create millions of inline buttons. Since the cap is 1024 what will happen to the other buttons?

Comment: Buttons are discard by the [LRU principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#LRU). You can ofc also change the size of the cache. Both is explained directly following the part of the wiki page that you cited.